# Random thumbnail positions on hover of randomly positioned text

Tags: html, css, random, position

I would like that when a user hovers different words, that a random arrangement of thumbnails fades-in.

Some caveats:

- thumbs should stay fairly close to the corresponding text.
- thumbs can overlap, but not fully.
- both the text and the thumb positions should be random on every page refresh
- text and thumbs shouldn't fall outside the screen.
- should be scalable (i.e.. I will have max. 10 texts and max. 10 thumbs for every text. the thumbs could spread concentrically if need be)

See the image for an example of what I mean:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```js
$("#button").hover(function() {
  $("#div1").toggle();
  $("#div2").toggle();
  $("#div3").toggle();
  $("#div4").toggle();
});
```

```css
#button {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.thumb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#div1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#div2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#div3 {
  margin-top: 210px;
  margin-left: 270px;
}

#div4 {
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="purchasing-tips">
  <div id="button">text</div>
  <div class="thumb" id="div1"><img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" /></div>
  <div class="thumb" id="div2"><img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/people" /></div>
  <div class="thumb" id="div3"><img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/tech" /></div>
  <div class="thumb" id="div4"><img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/nature" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please could you show us what you have tried? Also note that for true randomness you’ll need e.g. JavaScript.

Comment: done. it's a quite lame attempt, but it's a start.